# Resize the widgets if the window is resized if they were displayed with place

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a program that has about 12 widgets on the root window and all of them are placed using `.place(x,y)`.

The problem is that when the window is resized, everything stays in the same position and does not adjust to the window. Can this be fixed?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It requires you to do a lot more work. This is one of the reasons you should normally use `pack` or `grid`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

You can set the values of **`relwidth`** and **`relheight`** options to what you want (between *0.0* and *1.0*.) by using [`place_configure()`](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter.Place-class.html#place_configure) function:

```
your_widget_1.place_configure(relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
```

Alternatively, you can set the options I mentioned directly during the process of placing the widgets using [`place()`](http://mgltools.scripps.edu/api/DejaVu/Tkinter.Place-class.html#place) function. Example:

```
your_widget_1.place(bordermode=OUTSIDE,relheight=1.0, relwidth=1.0)
```

Comment: Maybe you could provide a simple runnable example?